# Почему происходит ошибка входа на сервер ms studio, хотя сервер существует?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ранее заходил на него. Сервер существует.

Comment: На какой сервер? Какая ошибка? Почему тег sql? Что таокое ms studio? Для тех, кто любит угадывать - ваш вопрос просто клад. Напишите по другому: я делаю то то и то то, скриншот. При этом просиходит то то и то то. скриншот. А я ожидаю вот того то и того то. ТОгда - возможно, помогут. Я так подозреваю, вы запускаете Microsoft Sql management Studio, и не можете присоединиться к SQL серверу. Так там в ошибке написано - почему. Ну, типа "не смогла, потому что сеть", "не смогла, потому что пароль неправильный". Может, пароль того пользователя поменяли, которым вы туда ходили

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по картинке - имеется в виду локально установленный у Вас же на компьютере сервер MS SQLEXPRESS.

Надо проверить в "сервисах" что он запущен. Примерно это выглядит так:

Как только Вы убедитесь, что у Вас эта строчка есть и он запущен - можно думать дальше. Но с высокой вероятностью с локально установленным сервером просто что то случилось, и он не запущен.

[image: как это обычно выглядит]